# How to disaggregate Stored Function Output phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I have created a stored function within phpmyadmin which calculates across several fields to derive an overall value. I'm using a function as the calculation needs to be used several times, across several scripts so to my knowledge, this is the most efficient way to do this to minimise code updates.

I've tested the function and it works in terms of providing an output, however when I combine it with my query, it provides an aggregated figure across the query results rather than a specific figure per row:

Function Code:

```
BEGIN   

DECLARE Output_needed INT(7);   

SET Output_needed = (select SUM(Col1+Col2+Col3) from table1);   

RETURN (Output_needed); 
END
```

SQL Query:

```
Select ID, function_name(), Col1, Col2, Col3 from table1
```

Required Query Output

```
ID  Function Returns    *Output_needed* Col1    Col2    Col3
1   100                 *10*             4      4       2
2   100                 *50*             10     20      20
3   100                 *5*              1      2       2
4   100                 *15*             10     2       3
5   100                 *20*              6     3       1
```

Can someone advise where I am going wrong? I assume I've missed a step somewhere but cant seem to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Pass any key field into your function and use that key in where condition

Comment: Is that just a case of altering the SQL query above or do i need to make changes to the function itself?

Comment: You have to use that key field in your function at where condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function select query doesn't have the condition to get the single row result.So, I have just added the one field for conditional use.

Function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `function_name`(pk_field INT) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE output_needed INT;
    SELECT SUM(Col1+Col2+Col3) INTO output_needed FROM table1 WHERE pk_field_name = pk_field;
    RETURN output_needed;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

SELECT Query:

```
Select ID, function_name(pk_field_name), Col1, Col2, Col3 from table1
```

Comment: works like a charm! Thank you so much for your help :)